# starts wondering/starts to wonder

Tags: word-choice, complementation

> 1. Ted still sits alone in the couch watching TV. He **starts wondering** where his wife is.
> 2. Ted still sits alone in the couch watching TV. He **starts to wonder** where his wife is.

I assume they are equally correct, but is there one of "starts wondering" and "starts to wonder" that sounds better to your ear than the other?

Comment: They're both correct but "starts to wonder" sounds better.

Comment: It's entirely subjective; what sounds better to one person will not sound as good to another. There is nothing wrong with either version.